# Two way binding with paper-toggle with dart angular

Tags: angular, angular-dart, 2-way-object-databinding, polymer-elements

I am trying to bind a model value to paper-toggle polymer element in dartangular.

```
 <paper-toggle-button [(checked)]="share.pin"></paper-toggle-button>
```

This is not working. It is only setting the toggle-button based on share.pin value but not the other way.

I tried adding a event handler but not successful .

```
 <paper-toggle-button [checked]="share.pin" (change)="share.pin=$event"></paper-toggle-button>
```

Comment: This is the correct way of two way data binding in angular 2. Is that the correct way in polymer?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
checked="{{share.pin::change}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <paper-toggle-button [(checked)]="share.pin">
> </paper-toggle-button>
> ```
>
> I tried adding a event handler but not successful .
>
> ```
> <paper-toggle-button [checked]="share.pin" (change)="share.pin=$event">
> </paper-toggle-button>
> ```

The two-way binding (banana in a box) syntax is really just syntactic sugar for a property binding and an event binding. Angular desugars the `paperToggleButton` binding into this:

```
<paper-toggle-button [checked]="share.pin" (checkedChange)="share.pin=$event">
</paper-toggle-button>
```

For more information, see [Angular Developer Guide - Template Syntax (Two-Way Binding)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way)

Comment: how do we know the event is (checkedChange) ? Where to check that?
The answer you suggested is not working.
One way to make it work is 
(change)="share.pin= !share.pin"